# scanf_s not writing character value

Tags: variables, char, parameter-passing, scanf

scanf_s not writing character value to variable. If I put a breakpoint to read the value of user_input, user_input will have a value of 0 instead of character value. If I declare user_input as a integer scanf_s will pass the int value correctly. Can someone tell me why or how I am using scanf_s wrong when using writing a char value? I am using Visual Studio 2013

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main(void)
   {
       char row, space, letter, user_input;
       printf("Enter a uppercase letter:"); 
       scanf_s(" %c", &user_input);

       for (row = 'A'; user_input >= row; ++row){
           for (space = user_input - row; space >= 1; --space){
               printf(" ");
           }
           for (letter = 'A'; row >= letter; letter++){
               printf("%c", letter);
           }
           for (letter = row -1; letter >= 'A'; letter--) {
               printf("%c", letter);
           }
           printf("\n");
       }
       getchar();
       getchar();
       return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scanf_s function need a addtion parameter for %c and %s.For example:

```
char user_input;
printf("Enter a uppercase letter:"); 
scanf_s(" %c", &user_input, 1);
printf("Input letter:%c\n", user_input);
```

You will can see user_input.
Note:scanf_s can check bound of char or chars type.